# Laravel Model - Function to return highest and lowest price

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, relationship

In Laravel I have an Offer Model and OfferPrice Model. The offer price has a 'personal' column which identifies if the price is a 'personal' price or 'business' price. What I would like to be able to do is call an offer with the price relationship and return the 'highest personal price', 'lowest personal price', 'highest business price' and 'lowest business price'.

My thoughts are to call something like:

```
Offer::with('Information', 'OfferPrice.highestPersonalPrice', 'OfferPrice.lowestPersonalPrice', 'OfferPrice.highestBusinessPrice', 'OfferPrice.lowestBusinessPrice')->get();
```

Which would return something like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "test offer",
    "description": "offer description",
    "Information": {
        "source": "Contact 1",
        "status": "3"
    },
    "max_personal_price": 1345.32,
    "min_personal_price": 456.43,
    "max_business_price": 1245.32,
    "min_business_price": 432.32
}
```

Here is an example of the current offer_prices table:

```
offer_id .   deposit .   price .  personal .   status .   expiry
1            300         1345.32  1            1          null
1            200         456.43   1            1          null
1            250         950.32   1            1          null
1            150         740.32   0            1          null
1            200         432.32   0            1          null
1            250         1245.32  0            1          null
```

Current offer model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;

class Offer extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'info_id','approved','expiry','branch_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */

    protected $hidden = ['deleted_at'];

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at'
    ];

    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\OfferPrice');
    }

    public function information()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Information');
    }

}
```

OfferPrice model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OfferPrice extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['offer_id', 'deposit', 'price', 'personal', 'expiry', 'status'];

    protected $hidden = ['status', 'offer_id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    protected $primaryKey = ['offer_id', 'deposit','personal'];

    public $incrementing = false;

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Offer');
    }

}
```

I've tried various different ways of trying to do this and nothing has yet come close to doing this. Hopefully there's a guru out there who knows their stuff :)

Comment: business is not in the model, business is identified where personal = 0

Answer (score 1):

Not able to understand your question very correctly, but if you want max and min price of OfferPrice model it will be `OfferPrice::max('price')` and `OfferPrice::min('price')` and if using relationship from Offer model it will be `Offer::first()->prices->max('price')` and `Offer::first()->prices->min('price')` I think you are getting some idea from my answer, you can try and let me know, if I have not understood your question, please comment on my answer or edit your question.

In OfferPrice model

```
public function scopePersonal($query, $param) {
    return $query->where('personal', 1);
}
```

and

```
$offer::(‘Information’)->prices()->personal(1)->max(‘price’);
```

Comment: The problem I’ve had with your solution is that it give you the max and min but not the business/personal max/min. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @Paul Can you use `personal` in place of `price` ?

Comment: It would need to be something like $offer::(‘Information’)->prices->where(‘personal’, ‘=‘, 1)->max(‘price’)->as(‘max_personal_price’)->prices->where(‘personal’, ‘=‘, 1)->min(‘price’)->as(‘min_personal_price’)->prices->where(‘personal’, ‘=‘, 0)->max(‘price’)->as(‘max_business_price’)->prices->where(‘personal’, ‘=‘, 0)->min(‘price’)->as(‘min_business_price’)->get(); but can’t get anything like that to work. This is because they need to return in lists as well as individual instances.

Comment: @Paul I think I got your issue, just create scope and apply that instead of that where clause and that should work fine.

Comment: @Paul Edited my answer, something around that should work for you.

Comment: That has worked on an individual instance, but not for a list instance, where there are a list of offers which need them all returning, such as Offer::with('Information')->where('approved', '=', 1 )->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();. Thank you for your help, to get this solution, I really appreciate it.